# Translate this SQL Query in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq-to-sql

How can I write a query similar to this one in LINQ to SQL

```
SELECT Id, (Distance - someValue) as Res
FROM Table
WHERE Res < someOtherValue
ORDER BY Res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyTable
.Where(m => m.Res < 4)
.OrderBy(m => m.Res)
.Select(m => new {Id, Res = m.Distance - 4});
```

...where 4 is your `someOtherValue`

Comment: Why would Res be an available column it was only created as an alias in the select?

Comment: You are just returning an Anonymous type, with only the fields you want...in this case, the Id and a custom-column called Red

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer keyword-style LINQ, it'd look something like this:

```
from x in theTable
where x.Distance < someOtherValue + someValue
orderby x.Distance
select new { x.Id, Res = x.Distance - someValue }
```

Comment: you can use the let statement to avoid calculating x.Distance - someValue twice, ie to create the alias, before you evaluate the where condition